# Adding a Sandboxed app to Login Items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have read through many questions here about launching my app on login. I have followed this [awesome tutorial](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) suggested many times. That tutorial does work. BUT...

The one side affect that comes from using a helper app and registering it using `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` is that my app does not show up inside the user's Login Items in System Preferences.

There are several apps in the App Store (such as PopClip and Dash) that do what I am trying to do. I just can't figure out how...

**UPDATE**: I found out from the Dash developer that Dash is actually not sandboxed. He also believes that PopClip is not either. This could explain things... https://alpha.app.net/kapeli/post/3975968

**UPDATE #2**: I just got confirmation from the PopClip dev that it indeed is not sandboxed as well. https://twitter.com/pilotmoon/status/313746294361427968

With the last 2 updates, I guess the answer is clear. As of today, there is no way to accomplish this with Sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's not too late.

In Apple's "[Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-BAJJBJEG)":

> ### Adding Login Items
>
> There are two ways to add a login item: using the `Service Management framework`, and using a shared file list.
>
> Login items installed using the Service Management framework **are not visible in System Preferences and can only be removed by the application that installed them**.
>
> Login items installed using a shared file list **are visible in System Preferences**; users have direct control over them. If you use this API, your login item can be disabled by the user, so any other application that communicates with it it should have reasonable fallback behavior in case the login item is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In sandboxed environment, only Helper applications can be installed in login items. You need to create one, stored in the `Contents/Library/LoginItems` folder of the main application.

Then you can used `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` to set the helper as login item and ask the login item to start the main application.

Comment: As you can see in the tutorial he linked to he knows the correct way to do this, the issue is showing the newly added item to the user in the PreferencePane, which you cannot do (it seems) when sandboxed.